# django-auth-ldap default values for newly created user

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

I have a Django app which has two authentication backends, an LDAP backend that has all 'internal' users and a custom backend having 'external' users. All internal users which match the LDAP group search filter should be created with `is_staff`: `True`.

Previously, we used

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "name": "cn",
    "email": "mail",
    "is_staff": "mail",
}
```

and this seemed to work just fine, however using Django 1.10 we now get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'me@example.com' value must be either True or False."]
```

I know I can search for group membership and match that to `is_staff` but basically I want **all** accounts for users that authenticate against LDAP automatically set to `is_staff`: `True`.

Is there a proper way to do this? I know I can fix it after the fact by hooking into the `django_auth_ldap.backend.populate_user` signal but then the user is already created, preferably I'd want to modify the user *before* they are created.

Answer (score 0):

The proper implementation would likely be with the `AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP` setting, as documented here: http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/users.html#easy-attributes

Specifically, if you can identify a group to which all of your users belong, you can have something like:

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_staff": "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
}
```